# std::enable_if to conditionally disable a template constructor

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to get a simple example to work to understand how to use `std::enable_if`, here is the problem:

I am reading the textbook C++ Templates The Complete Guide by David Vandevoorde, Nicolai M.Josuttis, Chapter 6, Section 5.

This chapter mentions: "`std::enable_if` to prevent being able to copy objects of a class template `C<>` if the template parameter is an integral type", and its following code:

```cpp
template <typename T> class C {
public:
  // user-define the predefined copy constructor as deleted (with conversion to
  // volatile to enable better matches)
  C(C const volatile &) = delete;
  // if T is not integral type, provide copy constructor template with better match:
  template <typename U,
            typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_integral<U>::value>>
  C(C<U> const &) {
    std::cout << "tmpl copy constructor" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

My question is, how should the above code be called and used?
for example, I tried:

```cpp
    C<int> c_int;
    std::string s = "sname";
    C<std::string> c_string1(std::string);
    C<std::string> c_string2(c_string1);
```

But give me compile error:

```sh
specialmember3.cc:22:39: error: no matching function for call to ‘C<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::C(C<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > (&)(std::string))’
   22 |     C<std::string> c_string2(c_string1);
      |                                       ^
specialmember3.cc:14:3: note: candidate: ‘template<class U, class> C<T>::C(const C<U>&)’
   14 |   C(C<U> const &) {
      |   ^
specialmember3.cc:14:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
specialmember3.cc:22:39: note:   mismatched types ‘const C<U>’ and ‘C<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >(std::string)’ {aka ‘C<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>)’}
   22 |     C<std::string> c_string2(c_string1);
      |                                       ^
specialmember3.cc:9:3: note: candidate: ‘constexpr C<T>::C() [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
    9 |   C() = default;
      |   ^
specialmember3.cc:9:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

Can someone please give me some hints or code guidance on how to use above template constructor?

Comment: The code looks weird to me. IIRC, default template arguments are not considered for SFINAE.

Comment: that book suffered huge amount of erratae in early printings, quality of its very depends on which version you use and there are incomplete (i.e. unusable) snippets.

Comment: That would be too bad, i just purchased the book a weeks ago from amazon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That class, as it is defined, is somewhat useless.

a) You can't default-initialize it, default constructor is removed. `C<int> c_int;` is ill-formed.

b) You can't create it from value, e.g. `C<std::string> c_string1(some_str);`, because that constructor does not exist.

Essentially you can copy it, but you cannot create it, which is a nonsense. It breaks rule of 3/5/0.

```
template <typename T> 
class C {
public:
  C() /*Initialization here */ {}
  C(const T& val) /*Initialization here */ {
      std::cout << "tmpl copy constructor: " << val << std::endl;
  }
  // user-define the predefined copy constructor as deleted (with conversion to
  // volatile to enable better matches)
  C(C const volatile &) = delete;
  // if T is not integral type, provide copy constructor template with better match:
  template <typename U,
            typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_integral<U>::value>>
  C(C<U> const &) {
    std::cout << "tmpl copy constructor" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

In that case those would be legal:

```
C<int> c_int;
std::string s = "sname";
C<std::string> c_string1(s);
C<std::string> c_string2(c_string1);
```

THe copy template defined disallows copying of C if T is integral, so

```
C<int> c_int2 (c_int); // use of deleted function 'C<T>::C(const volatile C<T>&)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `c_string1` as a function. I think you meant this

```
C<std::string> c_string1;
C<std::string> c_string2(c_string1);
```

Comment: WOW! thank for your answer, I think I misunderstood the usage of the above program

Comment: that won't compile